# embed bootstrap container inside IF PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, foreach

First of all, I tried almost all of solutions of similar questions but I cannot get results.
Im trying to alternate a design to show some data.
I have stored a list of products in

```
$prods = array()
```

So, when I try to foreach those products to alternate the way they get displayed on webpage, I did something like this:

```php
$aux = count($prods);
foreach($prods as $key => $value):?>
<?php if($aux%2 == 0): ?>
<html>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-around my-3">
            <figure class="col-6 figure my-3 row justify-content-center">
                <img style="height: 20vw" src="imagenes/d3.jpeg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="...">
            </figure>
            <div class="col-6 row justify-content-around">
                <div class="col row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col display-3"><?php $value ?></div>
                    <div class="col-12 display-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam saepe ipsum quod nesciunt labore magni a perspiciatis sunt officia facere, reprehenderit praesentium explicabo ipsa eligendi! Cumque nulla reiciendis perferendis sequi.</div>
                    <p class="col-12 lead">Precio: Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
<?php $aux = $aux-1; ?>

<?php else: ?>
<html>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-around my-3">
            <div class="col-6 row justify-content-around">
            <div class="col row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-12 display-3"><?php $value ?></div>
                    <div class="col-12 display-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam saepe ipsum quod nesciunt labore magni a perspiciatis sunt officia facere, reprehenderit praesentium explicabo ipsa eligendi! Cumque nulla reiciendis perferendis sequi.</div>
                <p class="col-12 lead">Precio: Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <figure class="col-6 figure my-3 row justify-content-center">
                <img style="height: 20vw" src="imagenes/d.jpeg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="...">
            </figure>

        </div>
    </div>
</html>
<?php $aux = $aux-1; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

When I run this only got blank results. No html code.
Im new to PHP/HTML/MongoDB so Im trying to learn! 
Thanks you.

Comment: can you check if the **$prods** contain data ?

Comment: Yes! @MohammedYassineCHABLI
`
(
    [5ebf256f2fbae00ee530fe13] => Fresh
    [5ebc2cf37f55c65188c7ce19] => Sunny
    [5ebc2c827f55c65188c7ce15] => Murder
)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally if your **$prod** is not empty , this should work :

```
<?php
$aux = count($prods);
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
foreach($prods as $key => $value){
    if($aux%2 == 0){ ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-around my-3">
                <figure class="col-6 figure my-3 row justify-content-center">
                    <img style="height: 20vw" src="imagenes/d3.jpeg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="...">
                </figure>
                <div class="col-6 row justify-content-around">
                    <div class="col row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col display-3"><?php $value ?></div>
                        <div class="col-12 display-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam saepe ipsum quod nesciunt labore magni a perspiciatis sunt officia facere, reprehenderit praesentium explicabo ipsa eligendi! Cumque nulla reiciendis perferendis sequi.</div>
                        <p class="col-12 lead">Precio: Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $aux = $aux-1; } else {?>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-around my-3">
                <div class="col-6 row justify-content-around">
                    <div class="col row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-12 display-3"><?php $value ?></div>
                        <div class="col-12 display-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam saepe ipsum quod nesciunt labore magni a perspiciatis sunt officia facere, reprehenderit praesentium explicabo ipsa eligendi! Cumque nulla reiciendis perferendis sequi.</div>
                        <p class="col-12 lead">Precio: Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <figure class="col-6 figure my-3 row justify-content-center">
                    <img style="height: 20vw" src="imagenes/d.jpeg" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="...">
                </figure>

            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $aux = $aux-1; ?>

    <?php }};?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I tried to put entire if statement inside an unique <html> tag but I didn't try to use <body>

Comment: Yes, effectively .